# Have people studied weakened forms of Tarski's axiom?

Tags: set-theory, axioms

My intuition about Grothendieck universes says the following.

1. Axiom of empty set $\leftrightarrow$ There exists a Grothendieck universe.
2. Axiom of infinity $\leftrightarrow$ There exist at least two distinct Grothendieck universes.
3. Tarski's axiom $\leftrightarrow$ There exist as many Grothendieck universes as there are entities in the domain of discourse.

Is this intuition correct? And if so, have people studied axioms that sit between 2 and 3? Say, asserting the existence of countably many distinct Grothendieck universes?

Comment: Certainly people have studied set theory under the assumption that inaccessible cardinals exist, which then gives the existence of at least three distinct Grothendieck universes.  (Not to mention the existence of stronger large cardinals which imply the existence of many inaccessibles.)

Comment: @ArthurFischer, so the intuition is correct?

Comment: A more usual definition of Grothendieck universe requires such a universe to contain an infinite set.

Comment: To amplify Arthur Fischer's comment, the existence of one inaccessible cardinal (which amounts to one Grothendieck universe in my view and three in your view) is exactly the assumption on which Solovay based his proof that, in the absence of the axiom of choice, it is consistent that all sets of real numbers are Lebesgue measurable.